# Web-based document archival

Tags: document-management

My company has lots of documents that we would like to move from files in a cabinet drawer to a web based application.  These documents are from projects that have been completed and need to archived.

Can anyone recommend a web based application that would let us do the above for both electronic and hard copy documents?

Comment: Are you wanting to host this yourself?

Comment: Ideally yes if it's not a lot of work to maintian,otherwise we can use the cloud

Comment: Do you want the webapp to keep track of what paper is in what hardware cabinet, or is a web-only app OK? I mean, after you have scanned and uploaded a paper, do you throw the paper, or put it in a box and don't worry about it anymore, or you still need to touch it physically sometimes?

Comment: Until the Star Trek transporter is invented it will be forever impossible to archive hard copy documents online, (the paper doesn't travel up the wire well), please rephrase your question to make it clearer whether you are talking about archiving __scans__ of hard copy documents or managing physical archives of them, e.g.: Storage Location, etc., _or both_.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul There will be 2 types of documents electronic (word, pdf, images etc) and hard copies.  The hard copies will be scanned and the and the physical copies will be destroyed after a fixed period and we sure the scanned copied are legible.

Answer (score 0):

I developed such a system for a famous international organization. It is quite easy to deploy at a smaller scale too.

## Usage

1. On the PC, put a document into the scanner
2. The document is automatically scanned, sent to Alfresco, and OCRed
3. Whenever you are looking for that document, just perform a search in the Alfresco web interface, you will be able to preview the document online and download it
4. If you need, you can sort the documents into folders, or use categories (first define a structure of categories and sub-categories), or use labels (more flexible than categories but less structured)
5. Upload any other files by drag-and-dropping them into the web interface, or by syncing them

A document seen in Alfresco:

[image: Alfresco Share preview]

## Installation

1. Find a server with enough RAM and disk space (RAM depends on the number of simultaneous users, disk depends on your data volume)
2. Install [Alfresco](https://www.alfresco.com/) on that server
3. Install [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) on that server
4. [Configure Alfresco to use Tesseract](http://alfrescosolutionsv.blogspot.jp/2014/07/alfresco-integration-with-tesseract.html)
5. Find a PC with a scanner
6. On that PC, install [CmisSync](http://cmissync.com/) and configure it to synchronize the scanner's output folder to Alfresco
7. Add an Alfresco rule that moves documents from that folder to another folder upon reception, or at the end of each day if you prefer